# Positon cursor at a specified location in yasnippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I have such a snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: test
# key: test
# condition: t
# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed) (yas/wrap-around-region 'nil))
# --

*** Expenses ""
```

After insert this snippet to org doc, the cursor is positioned at the head of next line.

How could place the cursion inside the string "?Cursor" of heading *** Expenses ""?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cursor ends up in the placeholder `$0` when present.  So, the snippet body should be

```
*** Expenses "$0"
```

BTW, the `yas/...` variables are obsolete, having been replaced by `yas-...` prefixes, eg. `yas-indent-line` and `yas-wrap-around-region`.